# How to access physical UI layer magento root directory in Bitnami over Azure vm

Tags: azure, magento, magento2, bitnami

I had deployed magento directly on Microsoft azure platform using BITNAMI(Linux platform), Everything works cool instead i cant able to access the physical directories of mlinux machine. Due to that facing trouble with installing the theme.

Comment: `physical directories of mlinux machine`? What do you mean? You could ssh to linux VM. If you want to access root directory. `sudo -i` change user to root.

Comment: If possible, could you share what bitnami product do you use? Maybe I could help you solve this.

Comment: Thanks, bitnami magento ubuntu 14.

Comment: Could you ssh to the VM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- get your key file or credentials to access the server via SSH / SFTP
- confirm SSH PORT ( 22 or 8888 )
- in bitnami, Magento is located at : /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/

make sure to allow firewall settings for port ( SSH )

you can find all information [here](https://docs.bitnami.com/azure/apps/magento/)

Answer (score 2):

If you want access to the filesystem inside the machine where you're running your application, you should connect to your Azure instance via SSH. For example, you can follow [this guide](https://docs.bitnami.com/azure/faq/#connecting-with-an-ssh-client).

Also, if you want to know how to obtain your credentials, you can follow [this guide](https://docs.bitnami.com/azure/faq/#obtaining-your-ssh-credentials-from-the-azure-marketplace).